# MySQL zero-filled ints and ifnull

Tags: mysql

Might be an odd combination, but I have a query that includes:

```
SELECT IFNULL(`active`.`num`, `generic`.`num`) AS `num` ...
```

`` `active` `` and `` `generic` `` are both aliases for the same table in this query, but `` `active` `` is joined based on user selection of which `` `num` `` to choose, whereas `` `generic` `` is an arbitrary one (typically the first, since that's how `GROUP BY` works) that will be shown if no specific one has been selected.

Anyway, `` `num` `` is a `SMALLINT(3) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL` column, but in the output the `ZEROFILL` is lost - this happens regardless of whether the `IFNULL` condition was met or not.

This might be a bug in MySQL, but how would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

Is there an option to add **LPAD**?

```
SELECT LPAD(IFNULL(`active`.`num`, `generic`.`num`), 3, '0') AS `num` ...
```

Comment: That'll work. Thanks. Still, weird that this happens since I sort of figured it would simply return the arguments it is given...

Comment: Maybe int 005 is equal to int 5, so SELECT IFNULL(null, 005), returns 5